# Mathematica TCP socket client toward Trading Platform

Tags: programming, data-acquisition, networking, real-time

I'd like to connect *Mathematica* with my Italian electronic trading platform.

To connect I need to open a TCP socket client towards the trading platform and send a string command.

The  high-level description (pseudo code) is like this:

```
- create new tcp socket on hostname="localhost and port ="5333"
- create out channel
- create input channel

- send request in string format 
   "function=subscribe|item=<stockCode>|schema=ask1;bid1;last_price"

- read response: if response is like outcom=OK then wait the push update

- read push update  

- close socket
```

But how I can do this with *Mathematica*?

Using JLink I should write something like this:

```
socket = new Socket(TCP_address, TCP_port);
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),
"UTF-8"));
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),
"UTF-8"));
//send request to T3 .
out.println(messagge);
//Wait response 
String response = in.readLine();
//[...]
//If response is outcome=OK wait push data
while(true){
String update = in.readLine();
//Thread to manage push data
}
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
//[...]
} catch (IOException e) {
//[...]
}
//[...]
```

But I'd like to know if is possible to avoid java and .net !

Comment: What do you mean by "create out channel" and "create input channel"? Is this something different than what one gets anyway with a TCP socket?

Comment: @OleksandrR. -- Often in these types of applications one may want high speed throughput, so one doesn't want two way traffic on a TCP socket.

Comment: This sounds like a job for JLink

Comment: @Jagra that is fair enough, but really my point was that pseudocode ought to provide a precise description of *how* to do something, not just a broad overview of what is desired. Since we don't know anything about what these channels are specifically, it's not really feasible to say how to create them using *Mathematica*. For all we know they could be messages passed over a Myrinet connection that need to contain timestamps accurate to the nanosecond. While this is possible, any practical implementation will have to explicitly take it into account.

Comment: So the only way is to use java library or .Net library ?

Comment: You can also write in C using LibraryLink or MathLink, or maybe even use netcat. In view of your Java example, I'd suggest removing "create out channel" and "create input channel" from the pseudocode, since it's now obvious that these are not crucial or even very relevant to the overall process.

Comment: To my knowledge, Mathematica doesn't have ready means to control the OS to do things like open TCP sockets.  For this reason, they made things like JLink, LibraryLink, and MathLink available.  They presumably did this so as not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @msalese May I ask you what is the purpose of this connection? I mean, I'm really interested in real applications for *Mathematica* in the Finance field. Please share more information with us, because the topic is very interesting!

Comment: Ok, I'm a retail option trader (buy side), what I need is to avoid DDE in Excel and use tcp from Mathematica to get realtime bid/ask. Bid/ask is used then to calibrate Implied Volatility Function. I would like to use excel only as GUI tool and let mathKernel to handle data (from the broker) and computation. Excel is connected to mathKernel through excelLink: http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/excel_link/

Answer (score 11):

I recently discovered SocketLink bundled with Mathematica. It's not documented, but super straightforward:

```
<< "SocketLink`"
port = 1234;
s = CreateClientSocket["host", port]
{inputStream, outputStream} = OpenSocketStreams[s];
```

This returns a binary InputStream and OutputStream that you can read/write like any other Mathematica stream with `BinaryRead` and `BinaryWrite`.

Edit: Highlighting @pickett's comment about the documented features available in 10.3 and later: [Mathematica 10.3 new Network Programming Features](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98462/mathematica-10-3-new-network-programming-features). (SocketLink is available in at least 10.0.2 and perhaps earlier.)

Comment: There is also the new networking functionality that the OP refers to [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98462/mathematica-10-3-new-network-programming-features), i.e. [`SocketConnect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketConnect.html) and friends.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- somehow I didn't find that after a while of searching.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98462/mathematica-10-3-new-network-programming-features

Answer (score 10):

Here is my sample code using JLink.
It's not a foolproof code, but if someone know haw to do better, please let me know.

The following code let Mathematica connect with T3Open Trading Software (Italian Broker WeBank), it expose some api that you can call with tcp socket. In this example I'm going to pass a list of options code (Terna Call) and take the ask/bid price.

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

t3OpenRequest [exchange_, market_, code_, schema_] := Module[
  {funSub, request, unsub, tcpaddress, tcpport, socket, out, in, 
   response},
  response = {};
  funSub = "function=subscribe|item=";
  unsub = "function=unsubscribe";
  (*ip addess and port where T3Open is running*)
  tcpaddress = "192.168.0.78";
  tcpport = 5333;
  (*build the string request to send*)
  request = 
   StringJoin[{funSub, exchange, ".", market, ".", code, "|schema=", 
     schema}];
  (*create a Socket object*)
  socket = JavaNew["java.net.Socket", tcpaddress, tcpport];
  out = JavaNew["java.io.PrintWriter", socket@getOutputStream[], True];
  in = JavaNew["java.io.BufferedReader", 
    JavaNew["java.io.InputStreamReader", socket@getInputStream[]]];
  (*send the request*)
  out@println[request];
  (*read the first response*)
  in@readLine[];
  (*read the second response, here are the data that I need*)
  response = Append[response , in@readLine[]];
  (*usubscribe the service*)
  out@println[unsub];
  (*close the socket*)
  socket@close[];
  Take[Flatten[StringSplit[response, "|"]], -1]
  ]
```

To use the function I prepare the options code list:

```
In[4]:= codeList01 = {{791308., 791309., 791310., 791311., 791312., 
   791313., 791314., 791315., 791316., 791317., 791318., 
   791319.}, {"TRN3G2.90", "TRN3G3", "TRN3G3.10", "TRN3G3.20", 
   "TRN3G3.30", "TRN3G3.40", "TRN3G3.50", "TRN3G3.60", "TRN3G3.70", 
   "TRN3G3.80", "TRN3G3.90", "TRN3G4"}}

Out[4]= {{791308., 791309., 791310., 791311., 791312., 791313., 
  791314., 791315., 791316., 791317., 791318., 791319.}, {"TRN3G2.90",
   "TRN3G3", "TRN3G3.10", "TRN3G3.20", "TRN3G3.30", "TRN3G3.40", 
  "TRN3G3.50", "TRN3G3.60", "TRN3G3.70", "TRN3G3.80", "TRN3G3.90", 
  "TRN3G4"}}

In[5]:= codeList02 = Transpose[codeList01]

Out[5]= {{791308., "TRN3G2.90"}, {791309., "TRN3G3"}, {791310., 
  "TRN3G3.10"}, {791311., "TRN3G3.20"}, {791312., 
  "TRN3G3.30"}, {791313., "TRN3G3.40"}, {791314., 
  "TRN3G3.50"}, {791315., "TRN3G3.60"}, {791316., 
  "TRN3G3.70"}, {791317., "TRN3G3.80"}, {791318., 
  "TRN3G3.90"}, {791319., "TRN3G4"}}
```

And here call the function using Table on all options:

```
In[10]:= data = 
 Table[t3OpenRequest["MI", "DER", ToString[code], schema], {code, 
   codeList02[[All, 1]]}, {schema, {"best_ask1", "best_bid1"}}]

Out[10]= {{{"0.0"}, {"0.0"}}, {{"0.1825"}, {"0.1405"}}, {{"0.089"}, \
{"0.0805"}}, {{"0.0325"}, {"0.027"}}, {{"0.0085"}, {"0.004"}}, \
{{"0.003"}, {"0.0005"}}, {{"0.003"}, {"0.0005"}}, {{"0.0015"}, \
{"0.0005"}}, {{"0.0015"}, {"0.0005"}}, {{"0.0"}, {"0.0"}}, {{"0.0"}, \
{"0.0"}}, {{"0.0"}, {"0.0"}}}

In[11]:= data01 = ToExpression[Flatten[data]]

Out[11]= {0., 0., 0.1825, 0.1405, 0.089, 0.0805, 0.0325, 0.027, \
0.0085, 0.004, 0.003, 0.0005, 0.003, 0.0005, 0.0015, 0.0005, 0.0015, \
0.0005, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}
```

Here the couples of ask and bid:

```
In[12]:= data02 = Partition[data01, 2]

Out[12]= {{0., 0.}, {0.1825, 0.1405}, {0.089, 0.0805}, {0.0325, 
  0.027}, {0.0085, 0.004}, {0.003, 0.0005}, {0.003, 0.0005}, {0.0015, 
  0.0005}, {0.0015, 0.0005}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}
```

Comment: now that you proofed that this is working it is maybe time to clean up your code a bit. avoid magic numbers inside your function (use options instead) and maybe move the whole thing into a package.