# Mathematica 10.3 new Network Programming Features

Tags: networking

Did someone already test the new Network programming function SocketConnect ?

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NetworkProgramming.html

Expecially on stock market data  ?

I wonder if now is possible to use the W-language for real time trading.

Comment: Writing real-time code in *Mathematica* has never been an intended use case and I don't know if it's even possible. Aside from that, why do you doubt that `SocketConnect` works as advertised?

Comment: Well I'm asking because I need to evaluate to upgrade to new version.

Comment: Your best option would probably be to ask WRI for a trial copy and then test it yourself for your intended application. Personally, I would be extremely wary of trying to write real-time code in *Mathematica* that, if it doesn't work as expected, could cause significant monetary losses.

Comment: [WRI does not recommend the use of (*Mathematica*) for applications in which errors and/or omissions could threaten life, injury, or significant loss.](http://www.wolfram.com/legal/agreements/wolfram-mathematica.html)

Comment: Thanks to all, yes I'll go for a 10.3 trial copy and test the new SocketConnect function. But what seems strange to me is that WRI sells a Financial Platform with which one can do algotrading , now why not capture live market data with new socket function and than apply trading rules on ? Of course WL-platform is not suitable for HFT trading but should be fine if sampling frequency is 1 minute.

Comment: "why not capture live market data with new socket function and than apply trading rules on?" - well, consider it as one experiment you'll have to do. As noted, though, you're doing said experiment at your own risk, and you won't have much to blame if your strategy goes belly up.

Comment: @msalese How did it go with your attempt to use Mathematica for algo trading? Anything new?

Comment: @Rod I gave up (for the moment), I'm using Mathematica as analysis tool but implementing strategies with F# + [FCell.io](http://fcell.io) + DDE-Excel. I want stay focussed on trading, for that reason I'm investigating F# both for data analysis that for the implementation of trading strategies.

Comment: @msalese I don't use Wolfram Finance Platform (relying instead on my own Bloomberg-to-Mathematica interface), but I think the idea is that Mathematica is good for data analysis, risk modeling, and reporting. I don't know of anybody who has written an automated trading system in it. Among other problems, it's relatively slow.